# Jsoup авторизация на сайте с headers

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup, token, response

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане.

## Есть работающий код на питоне. Вот он:

```
import requests
url = 'https://nlstar.com/ru/office4/login/'
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)
csrf_token = r.cookies['csrftoken']
data = {
    'login':        '007-2400101',        'password':         '377609',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token
}
d = s.post(url, data=data, headers=dict(Referer=url))
dd = s.get('https://nlstar.com/')
print(dd.text)
```

При попытке перевести его в java (jsoup) и отправка запроса возникает ошибка 403. HTTP error fetching URL.

Можете подсказать как сделать? (GET запрос проходит, но не авторизируется)

Вот мой код:

```
    try {

        String token = "";
        String Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36";
        String URL="https://nlstar.com/ru/office4/login/";
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup
                .connect("https://nlstar.com")
                .userAgent(Agent)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .timeout(5000)
                .execute();

        Document doc = response.parse();
        token = response.cookie("csrftoken");

        response = Jsoup
                .connect(URL)
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
               // .data("redirect_to","/ru/office4/business/")
                .userAgent(Agent)
               // .header("Referer",URL)
                .data("csrfmiddlewaretoken", token)
                .data("login", "007-2400101")
                .data("password", "377609")
                //.cookies(response.cookies())
                .execute();
        // С этого места мы уже авторизированны и работаем с сайтом .

        Jsoup
                .connect("https://nlstar.com/ru/office4/business/")
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .execute();
        Document doc2 = response.parse();

        String mm = doc2.title();
        output = "Сайт: " + mm + "\n" + getTimeStamp();


    }
 catch (IOException e) {
     output = e.toString();
     System.out.println(e.toString());
 }
```